# Movies on philosophy similar to "Waking Life"?

Tags: free-will, existence, psychology, existentialism, death

The movie [**"Waking Life"**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uk2DeTet98o) is a philosophical masterpiece: a quasi non-narrative psychedelic dreamscape exploring the very nature of both existence and non-existence in unpredecented depth.

In a sequence of seemingly unrelated dialogues, the film addresses anything from the nature of love and death to the paradox of free will, starring three philosophy professors ([**Louis Mackey**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louis_H._Mackey), [**Robert Solomon**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_C._Solomon) & [**David Sosa**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Sosa)) and several other contemporary philosophers ([**Eamonn Healy**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eamonn_Healy), [**Aklilu Gebrewold**](http://wakinglifemovie.net/Transcript/Chapter/6), [**Caveh Zahedi**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caveh_Zahedi), [**Timothy "Speed" Levitch**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timothy_Levitch), ...), summarizing the best of European, Asian and African philosophy alike.

Waking Life is by far my favorite movie; and I can't think of even a single movie that comes remotely close to the philosophical depth that I find in Waking Life. Can you? Or to phrase it differently: can you recommend any movies similar to Waking Life?

---

#### Edit :

Of all the movies I've ever seen so far, [**The Congress**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1rNSTizOsws) is the one I know that is close to "Waking Life" and [**"A Scanner Darkly"**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TY5PpGQ2OWY) (that other animated masterpiece by Linklater) both from an audiovisual perspective and from a philosophical perspective.

Comment: I love that movie, but it is not just a movie about philosophical ideas. It is also a movie about the fascinating phenomenon of [Lucid Dreaming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucid_dream), and it does a fantastic job depicting it.

Comment: It's not another *Waking Life* but you might enjoy the excellent Speed Levitch documentary *[The Cruise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Cruise_%281998_film%29)*.

Comment: How about all of Woody Allen's movies combined? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jbnueb2OI4o

Comment: "Is the Man Who is Tall Happy?" is an interview with Noam Chomsky.  It has a certain overlap both in style and in the nature of its content.

Comment: Funny. I was going to mention "The Congress" until I read your edit. There's also "The Fountain" if you're looking for similar qualities in film, but Žižek's *Pervert's Guide* (1 on Cinema, 2 on Ideology) are more explicit works of cinematic philosophy, as answered below.

Answer (score 4):

*Waking Life* is somewhat *sui generis*, but I would highly recommend "[The Possibility of Hope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Possibility_of_Hope)," a documentary by *Gravity* director Alfonso Cuaron, included as a DVD extra with his incredible *[Children of Men](http://popculturephilosopher.com/top-ten-movies-children-of-men/)*.  Depending on your opinion of Slavoj Zizek, you might also enjoy his "[Pervert's Guide to Cinema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Pervert%27s_Guide_to_Cinema)."  A movie that is less explicitly philosophical, but that shares some similar themes of reality and identity (as well as a certain psychedelic sensibility) is the Gondry/Kaufman classic "[Eternal Sunshine of the Spotless Mind](http://popculturephilosopher.com/reconstructivist-art-eternal-sunshine/)."

If it was the style of the film that appealed to you, I can't immediately identify any full-length animated films that are comparable, but there are some excellent philosophical shorts, including [More](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cCeeTfsm8bk), [Vrykutasy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=79PmZVhb0DM), and [Balance](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1CTesYaduBA).  There's also Don Hertzfeldt's [Everything Will Be OK](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1IUX0Qy-IDM) and [World Of Tomorrow](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XdV1uFwtCpo).

Comment: From a philosophical perspective, I prefer "Human Nature" to "Eternal Sunshine of the Spotless Mind". It has the same Gondryesque humor, but it goes a bit deeper into the more interesting aspects of... well... human nature. I can't say I've ever heard of "The Possibility of Hope" or "Pervert's Guide to Cinema", so +1 for these suggestions ;-)

Comment: Kaufman is always good for an intellectual workout.  His [Synecdoche, New York](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synecdoche,_New_York) is another one that takes on the meaning of reality.  I've also heard good things about his new [Anomolisa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anomalisa), but I haven't seen it myself.

Comment: I'm not really that much into Charlie Kaufman. I'm more into directors like David Cronenberg (eg. [**Cosmopolis**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q3ZmIwteUAY)), Darren Aronofsky (eg. [**Requiem For A Dream**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lgo3Hb5vWLE)) or Terry Gilliam (eg. [**Tideland**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=88sS5L5KYu4)). [**Feel free to check out my personal top 100**](http://www.imdb.com/list/ls058496130/)

Comment: I added some animated shorts to the above answer.

Comment: Ever seen [**The Congress**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1rNSTizOsws)? Of all the movies I've ever seen so far, it's the one I know that is closest to "Waking Life" and [**"A Scanner Darkly"**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TY5PpGQ2OWY) both from an audiovisual perspective and from a philosophical perspective.

Answer (score 3):

In the spirit of providing an answer to your question rather than adding to the pile of everyone's favorite philosophically-minded movies, please a take a moment to review [The Cognitive Science Movie Index](https://www.indiana.edu/~cogfilms/index.php). Although the aim is CogSci and not philosophy specifically, [it could be argued](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cinema_1:_The_Movement_Image) that all cinema is anyway always already a reflection of philosophy.

Since you mentioned *Waking Life* specifically, and indicated your interest was directed more at movies with explicit or more immediately relevant themes and concepts, *The Index* will likely be right up your alley— *Waking Life* is included in the list as well, and there is a severe amount of overlap between the fields. The site was originally referred to me by Rob Goldstone at a conference on just such a crossover, regarding the concept of cognitive penetration.

I'd recommend to anyone interested in this question, adding your own finds to the list and helping it grow.